# Media Queries conflict using max-device-width and max-width

Tags: css, media-queries

I am trying to understand if there's any conflict between using `max-device-width` to specify certain elements for a website to be responsive on devices and using `max-width` for desktops. I've heard from forums that by using `device-width` in your stylesheets gives you a different layout on your devices?

Will there be any conflicts in the sense of being overwritten?

This is what I have so far:

```
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1824px) {...}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1224px) {...}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {...}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 768px) {...}

/* Big smartphones (portrait)*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 640px) {...}

/* Big smartphones (portrait)*/
@media only screen and (max-width : 480px) {...}

/* Smartphones (portrait) */
@media only screen and (max-width : 321px) {...}


/* Only iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio : 1.5) {
/* YOUR STYLE GOES HERE */
}


/* Smartphones (portrait) */
@media only screen and (max-device-width : 768px) {...}
```

Answer (score 1):

max-device-width refers to the device's actual screen width

max-width refers to the viewport width.

They will only ever conflict one another when the viewport width is variable.

So if you use max-width and then resize your browser window to a narrow width ie reduce the viewport width - then your mobile rules will kick in.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you want:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) {

  /* Small screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 320px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 320px) { 

  /* Small screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {

  /* Medium screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 700px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 700px) { 

  /* Medium screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

  /* Large screen, non-retina */

}

@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (   min--moz-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1)    and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)      and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi) and (min-width: 1300px),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx)  and (min-width: 1300px) { 

  /* Large screen, retina, stuff to override above media query */

}
```

And the pixel density devices list: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Comment: Shouldnt `min-device-pixel-ratio` kick in only for retina-ready devices, ie iphones and ipads? else, it would just focus on `min-width` for desktops?

Comment: No Sir, even mine Lenovo Z500 ideapad notebook with chrome has its pixel ratio as you can see here: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/  :)